# How would I go about Getting a breakdown (and sum of population) of all groups of countries based on first letter

Tags: mysql

I don't have a clue how to do this one I am looking for results that will be a letter for every character in the alphabet and then a value for that letters total population for example I know Z is supposed to equal 61,000,000 also the next 4 queries I have to write have to do with making tweaks to this query so I have to figure it out I am pouring over my text book but not having any luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select substring(nationCol,1,1) as firstletter, sum(populationcol) as sumpop from tablewithnationnames group by firstletter

If you need every letter , and there are some letters without a country, then you'll need to left join and alphabet table with the result of this query

Comment: SELECT substring(name,0,1) as firstletter, sum(population)as sumpop from country group by firstletter This only returns 1 row firstletter is empty and sumpop is around 7 billion (total world population. I need to get a return of 26 rows with a population for each letter. any other ideas.

Comment: that gets me the all the letters thank you so much for helping out with this